# How to use "$ref" in json schema properly

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to make a *single file* JSON schema. I'm trying to use `"$ref"` to to avoid repetition:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "appMethods": {
      "about": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "author": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/appMethods"
  }
}
```

In my understanding, this should be equivalent to

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "about": {
        "type": "string"
      },
    "author": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

But all of the online schema validators I've tried said:

> ```
> Unexpected token encountered when reading value for '$ref'. Expected StartObject, Boolean, got String. Path 'properties.$ref', line 15, position 38.
> ```

Where is the mistake and what is it?

Answer (score 5):

The thing is that `$ref` doesn't work *everywhere*, it works only in places where a `schema` is expected. Only `schema` can be substituted via `$ref`, not "any piece of JSON".

`properties` expects key-value pairs where values represent a schema, not a schema itself. The parser doesn't try to lookup for a schema here, it expects an object proper.

Sadly, this limits my schema quite a bit (I can't check for certain properties - like required - and forced to either allow some invalid json or resort to a huge repetition).

Comment: You can still use `required`.

Comment: It's required only in one case among several. If I mark it as `required`, all the usages of `appMethods` will require `name` (the required key) present, but this would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that needs to declare correct poperty member which describe the schema definitions.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "appMethods": {
      "about": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "author": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "appMethods": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/appMethods"
    }
  }
}
```

json validator: 
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: But this one is different from the schema in my post. Yours allows only one key, `appMethods`, which type is unrestricted.

Comment: Oh really? I 'm just see the appMethods been defined on your definitions schema.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a set of properties shared by multiple objects one can do this (please excuse my YaML rather than JSON):

```
definitions:
  shared:
    type: object
    properties:
      sharedProp:
        type: string
allOf:
  - $ref: "#/definitions/shared
  - type: object
    properties:
      specificProp:
        type: array
        ....
```

The idea here is that none of the schemas listed prohibits properties not listed in the schema. If you want to forbid any properties not shared or not explicitly listed this does not work.